# Sqlalchemy psycopg2 set socket options

Tags: sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'd like to try setting the socket options for a psycopg2 postgres database connection to do abortive connection releases. We are facing an issue similar to that described here: https://www.box.com/blog/container-networking-mystery-missing-rsts/.

There's an example of setting socket options for a MySQL connection here: https://github.com/mozilla/mozpool/blob/master/mozpool/db/pool.py, but I can't seem to access the socket with a psycopg2 connection.

Is it possible to set socket options using a psycopg2 connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [connection.fileno](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.fileno) to get the file number of the socket and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what I ended up doing: sock = socket.fromfd(conn.fileno(), socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).